# android subtract one input from another

Tags: android, textview, user-input

I have 2 objects

```
obj.targetWeight = targetWeight.getText().toString();
obj.currentWeight = currentWeight.getText().toString();
```

I want to subtract one from the other.

I have tried this with no luck.

```
if (obj != null){
    outputEditText.setText("Your target weight is " + obj.targetWeight + 
                            "\n Your current weight is " + obj.currentWeight + "\n" 
                        + (obj.currentWeight - obj.targetWeight));
}
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't what should be done however I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert them to integers first.

```
if (obj != null) {
    int targetWeight = Integer.parseInt(obj.targetWeight.getText().toString());
    int currentWeight = Integer.parseInt(obj.currentWeight.getText().toString());
    outputEditText.setText(
        "Your target weight is " + obj.targetWeight + "\n" + 
        "Your current weight is " + obj.currentWeight + "\n" +
        "Difference is " + (currentWeight - targetWeight));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the code sample to show where the code snippet I entered should go and how to use it. If that still is not what you want, can you update your question as to what you mean by it not working?

Comment: hi.
thanks for your reply. i get the following error on "(targetWeight.getText().toString());        Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type int" (same applies for currentweight)

Answer (score 0):

with thanks to kailoon i have an answer.

```
if (obj != null) {
        int targetWeight = Integer.parseInt(obj.targetWeight);
        int currentWeight = Integer.parseInt(obj.currentWeight);
        outputEditText.setText(
            "Your target weight is " + obj.targetWeight + "\n" + 
            "Your current weight is " + obj.currentWeight + "\n" +
            "Difference is " + (targetWeight - currentWeight ));
        }
```